# Get last row ignoring formula in google script

Tags: row, formula, move

I used a google script that move row from one sheet to another from column A to column D. On column E i have a formula. How can i put data on last row from Column A to D from example, ignoring formula from column E. Can someone help me with this?

```
function onEdit(e){
  let r = e.range;
  if (r.columnStart != 4 || r.rowStart == 1 || e.value == null) return;
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const valArray = ["Waiting","In progress","Complete"];
  const destArray = ["Order","Open order","Complete order"];
  let dest = sh.getSheetByName(destArray[valArray.indexOf(e.value)]);
  let src = sh.getActiveSheet();
  if (dest.getName() == src.getName()) return;
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,4).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,4));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
}
```

**Here an example of my problem, maybe this will explain better:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qowADCPYiyej25ezXtjVLO5fvg9Gr9rolX3bh2-ZAG4/edit#gid=0**

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `How can i get last row from Column G from example, ignoring column W.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Hi. Here an example of my problem, maybe this will explain better: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qowADCPYiyej25ezXtjVLO5fvg9Gr9rolX3bh2-ZAG4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: My English is not that good. Thank you for your interest and help. In my example, I use the script to move the line from "Order" to "Open Order" or "Complete Order", depending on the "Status" (in column D). For example, if the status is "In progress", go to "Open order", if the status is "Completed", go to "Complete Order" and it works fine, but if I have a formula in column E or any other column , it puted after the formula. In my example it move to "Open Order", but on row 9 instead of row 3, because I have a formula on the Column E.

Comment: I want to move data from A to D after the last line with data not'after the formula. I don't know now if I explain very well because as I said my English is not so good.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your replying and your question of `I used a google script that move row to another sheet from column A to column V. On column W i have a formula. How can i get last row from Column G from example, ignoring column W.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `dest.getLastRow()` by `dest.getLastDataRow('A')` and add this function:

```
Object.prototype.getLastDataRow = function(col){
  var lastRow = this.getLastRow();
  var range = this.getRange(col + lastRow);
  if (range.getValue() !== "") {
    return lastRow;
  } else {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }  
};
```

I still sugest you to erase all formulas in column E and put in E1

```
={"price * 2";ARRAYFORMULA(if(C2:C>0;C2:C*2;""))}
```

so that the formula will populate / will be active the new row

Comment: Hi thanks for idea. I tried but it dosn't work. It create a new row and move data there. if my sheet have 1000 rows, script create one new row and put data there at 1001.

Comment: ok, sorry, I have updated my answer

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution seems to be what i be needing.